# How to fix this error when clicking the button?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

How do I make a button to copy a message?

I tried to do like this:

```
const rowCopyPaste = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents(new Discord.MessageButton()
   .setLabel('Copy and Paste')
   .setStyle('SECONDARY')
   .setCustomId('copy_paste_button'));

embedMessage = await interaction.user.send({
   embeds: [
      new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#2F3136')
      .setTitle(interaction.user.username)
      .setDescription('Test')
   ],
   components: [rowCopyPaste]
});

const CollectorCopyPaste = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
   componentType: 'BUTTON',
   time: 5000 * 60,
   filter: i => i.user.id === interaction.user.id && i.customId === 'copy_paste_button',
});

CollectorCopyPaste.on('collect', async i => {
   i.channel.send({
      embeds: [new Discord.MessageEmbed()
         .setDescription('Message to be copied')
      ]
   });
});
```

But when the button is clicked, this error: **This interaction failed**

If you can help me I will be grateful

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: That's probably not the whole error message, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to reply to button interaction, so in your case that would be

```js
i.reply({
  embeds: [
   new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setDescription('Message to be copied')
  ]
});
```

inside of the  `CollectorCopyPaste.on('collect', async i => {...})` instead of

```js
i.channel.send({
      embeds: [new Discord.MessageEmbed()
         .setDescription('Message to be copied')
      ]
   });
```

Comment: Still with the same error